# The following file has two different outputs in xelatex and PDFlatex. why?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, italic

My file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl}\normalfont\itshape
This text with xelatex should be italic. Is it Italic?
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

`Outputs`:
[image: 1]

And also:
[image: 2]

Thanks for your responsibility.

Comment: I get italic for either pdflatex and xelatex (and also luatex). In which one do you get upright text? How do you compile?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you have an old version of latex, at least 2 years old then I assume?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Running `pdftex --version` I get `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`. According to my Ubuntu repository, it is the latest version available for my Ubuntu version (`Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`). Is it possible/safe to update to another version? Using the Zesty repositories, maybe?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik prior to 2015 xelatex (despite being a unicode engine) defaulted to 7-bit OT1 encoding, the same as latex, but since then xelatex and lualatex have changed to default to TU encoding. texlive 2016 and texlive 2017 have been out for ages and texlive 2018 is starting testing, but I don't know how that corresponds to the debian repo versions. texlive 2015 is rather old, especialy if you are using xetex or luatex which see more changes than pdftex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the clarification! I'll stick to the 2015 version for now, and wait for the next stable release of Ubuntu, that will be in a few months. I read somewhere that it is not recommended to upgrade packages to future releases (I don't know to what extent this is true for texlive). I mostly use pdfTeX, so I should be fine for the time being `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX does warn you about this, the terminal output is

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ppl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 3.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ppl/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 3.
```

There are no fd files set up for a font family called `ppl` in unicode (TU) encoding.

If you use `fontspec` and refer to a suitable opentype font family `fd` files are not required.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}\itshape
This text with xelatex should be italic. Is it Italic?
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```